# selectedOptions is not updating on MatselectionList with ngModel

Tags: angular, angular-ngmodel

I have MatSelectionList with different Classes.
First time when I select classes it will associate student into this classes.

This is working fine, but the problem is when I go to dialog again and select the student who already selected classes then checkbox with existing classes are not checked.

I am pushing associated classes id into selectedOptions.
selectedOptions contains the Value but it is not updating Ui.

HTML contents

```html
<mat-selection-list [(ngModel)]="selectedOptions" ngDefaultControl>
  <mat-list-option *ngFor="let class of Classes" [value]="class.class_id">
    {{class.ClassName}}
  </mat-list-option>
</mat-selection-list>
```

Component contents

```js
@Component(...)
export class MyComponent { 
  
  selectedOptions: string[] = [];

  constructor(private service:StudentService){
    this.service.getStudentElement().subscribe((result)=> {
      this.selectedStudents.forEach((student) => {
        this.filteredStudents = result.filter(studentElement => {
          return studentElement.student == student.uid;
        });
      this.associatedClassForSelectedStudents(this.filteredStudents);
    })
  })

  associatedClassForSelectedStudents(selectedStudents: any){
    selectedStudents.forEach(element=> {
      if(element.class){
        this.selectedOptions.push(element.class)
      }
    })
  }

}
```

Value emitted by `this.service.getStudentElement()` subscriber:

```js
[
  {
    student: "261a134847d-e814379eaea6"
    uid: "9dd97ede-8943-b8f471317d14"
    class: "11111111-ee9d-ed1401907fa9"
   }
]
```

Can anyone tell me what am i doing wrong?

Thank you

Comment: Assuming that the value of `Classes` is a static array, your HTML seems correct. This means your ".ts" or the remainder of the template are the cupid. To get better help you will need to share more of the code.

Comment: Hello @TheFabio i have Updated My Question. Thank you For quick Answer.

Comment: @TheFabio Classes are Array Of Object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `this.selectedOptions.push(element.class)` it's not changing the reference to the `selectedOptions` and that's why it is not seen as a change and the selected classes are not updated.

You can try to use `concat` method that would create a new array:

`this.selectedOptions = this.selectedOptions.concat(element.class)`

Comment: I have Tried it already and It is not working. Thank you for you answer.

Comment: Maybe you can add the full content of the .ts and .html files, as it's not clear to me where the Classes are initialized. Also, what do you mean "select the same student"? The selected classes are not being updated in the ui? Or the selectedOptions are not actually updated at all?

Comment: i figured out the issue my uid is long and ng-value-reflect is not taking whole id that's why it is not coming in ng-reflect-model. if you have any solution please suggest.